# Is it possible to restore a single project plan from a full database backup

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

Using MS Project 2013, one of our PCO deleted tasks from a project plan, while work had been entered via timesheets on those same tasks, some of which weren't approved, yet.

The project is now in a situation where it cannot be published because it is waiting on updates (the work that was entered but not approved), AND the updates cannot be applied as they pertain to tasks that no longer exist.

We are using single-entry mode, and the setting indicating that work can only be added through timesheets.

As for the obvious solution, we realized that item-level backups were not set up on our SharePoint server ; we only have our enterprise's full database backups.

I might be able to clone that server, restore a full DB backup containing that project plan before the tasks' deletion, and I wonder whether that would allow me to restore that project plan only from the new instance?